# Query Hive table using ROWNUM

Tags: hive

How can I query a Hive table specific to row number.

For example :

Let say I want to print out all records of Hive table from row number 2 to 5.

Answer (score 1):

I actually recently  updated the documentation regarding the offset option

`... order by ... limit 1,4`

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Select#LanguageManualSelect-LIMITClause

Answer (score 0):

This answer seems like what you're asking:

[SQL most recent using row_number() over partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402850/sql-most-recent-using-row-number-over-partition)

In other words:

```
SELECT user_id, page_name, recent_click
FROM (
  SELECT user_id,
         page_name,
         row_number() over (partition by session_id order by ts desc) as recent_click
  from clicks_data
) T
WHERE recent_click between 2 and 5
```