# Remove duplicates in NiFi

Tags: mysql, apache, duplicates, apache-nifi

I have a flow QueryDatabaseTable->ConvertRecord->PutElasticseachHttpRecord
What I am trying to do is fetching the full data from MySQL database and feeding it into Elasticsearch to perform analytics on it using Kibana. However, my data has duplicate columns like below:(Highlighted in black are the only repeating value)

ID,Machine Name,value1,Value2,Date

1, **abc, 10, 34**, 2018-09-27 10:40:10

2, **abc, 10, 34**, 2018-09-27 10:41:14

3,**abc, 10, 34**, 2018-09-27 10:42:19

4, xyz, 12, 45, 2018-09-27 10:45:19

So In my table ID is primary key and Timestamp fields keep updating. What I want to achieve is to fetch only one record for particular **Machine Name**. Example below show what output table I want:

**ID,Machine Name,value1,Value2,Date**

1, abc, 10, 34, 2018-09-27 10:40:10

4, xyz, 12, 45, 2018-09-27 10:45:19

How can I achieve this in NiFi? The objective is to drop/delete the duplicate columns. If it's possible please tell me which processor to use and what configs to set?

**I am getting following error in QueryRecord processor:**
[image: QueryRecord Error]

[image: QueryRecord Error]

[image: QueryRecord Error2]

Any suggestion is much appreciated.
Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `convertrecord` processor, use ***[QueryRecord processor](https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/121794/running-sql-on-flowfiles-using-queryrecord-process.html)***.

Add new SQL query using [row_number() window function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27402850/sql-most-recent-using-row-number-over-partition) and `Partition by Machine Name,value1,value2...etc` and select only the **first row** in each partition data.

> ***QueryRecord Configs:***

I tried with `Csv reader` and `Json set Writer` controller services

***Query:***

```
select id,machinename,value1,value2,"date" from(
SELECT id,
         machinename,value1,value2,"date",
         row_number() over (partition by machinename order by "date" asc) as rn
  from FLOWFILE
) sq
WHERE rn = 1
```

[image]

**Output:**

```
[ {
  "id" : "1",
  "machinename" : "abc",
  "value1" : "10",
  "value2" : "34",
  "date" : "2018-09-27 10:40:10"
}, {
  "id" : "4",
  "machinename" : "xyz",
  "value1" : "12",
  "value2" : "45",
  "date" : "2018-09-27 10:45:19"
} ]
```

**Flow:**

```
QueryDatabaseTable->QueryRecord->PutElasticseachHttpRecord
```

Incase if you are having **space** in `machine name column name` then `enclose column name in double quotes("<col_name>")` use below query

```
select id,"machine name",value1,value2,"date" from(
SELECT id,
         "machine name",value1,value2,"date",
         row_number() over (partition by "machine name" order by "date" asc) as rn
  from FLOWFILE
) sq
WHERE rn = 1
```

i have included only `machine name` column in partition by clause but you can include other columns `value1,value2` as per your requirements.

Use [this](https://github.com/shureddy/Templates/blob/Dynamic_convertion_from_json_to_csv/Row_number.xml) template for more reference.

Comment: @shrads, Please check the updated answer, i have included all sql statements also..!!

Comment: Thank you replying. Please see my updated question error image. I have used CSVreader and JsonRecordSetWritter but getting an error in QueryRecord.  Please help me resolve that error. Thank you!

Comment: @shrads, **Output format** from **QueryDatabaseTable** will be in **Avro**, So in QueryRecord processor you need to Use **AvroReader** instead of CsvReader and You can choose your writer as per your requirements. for more reference use this template **https://github.com/shureddy/Templates/blob/Dynamic_convertion_from_json_to_csv/Row_number.xml**

Comment: I tried using avro reader but now its showing error as "column Id" not found in any table. CAn you help me resolbe this? Thank you! I have attached error image in the main question.

Comment: Can you share your template? The link you shared on exporting and loading in NiFi says "Not a valid format".

Comment: @shrads,Weird same template i'm able to save and upload to NiFi, i re uploaded  new template try again now.Regards to ERROR **compare the flowfile schema(case sensitive)** with the schema that you have defined in **avro reader** and change the **schema,sql** query matching with the schema.

Comment: Thank You! It worked fine :) I appreciate your time and effort. You have solved my big problem :)